# Fastest way to render 2D tiles using LWJGL?

Tags: java, opengl, 2d, lwjgl

I started watching [these](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLILiqflMilIxta2xKk2EftiRHD4nQGW0u) tutorials for creating a 2d top-down game using LWJGL and I read that VBO's should be fast but for rendering 48*48 tiles per frame I get only about 100FPS which is pretty slow because I will add a lot more stuff to the game than just some static, not moving or changing, tiles.

What can I do to make this faster? Keep in mind that I just started learning lwjgl and opengl so I probably won't know many things.

Anyways, here are some parts of my code (I removed some parts from the code that were kinda meaningless and replaced them with some descriptions):

The main loop

```
double targetFPS = 240.0;
        double targetUPS = 60.0;

        long initialTime = System.nanoTime();
        final double timeU = 1000000000 / targetUPS;
        final double timeF = 1000000000 / targetFPS;
        double deltaU = 0, deltaF = 0;
        int frames = 0, updates = 0;
        long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();

        while (!window.shouldClose()) {
            long currentTime = System.nanoTime();
            deltaU += (currentTime - initialTime) / timeU;
            deltaF += (currentTime - initialTime) / timeF;
            initialTime = currentTime;

            if (deltaU >= 1) {
                // --- [ update ] ---
                --INPUT HANDLING FOR BASIC MOVEMENT, CLOSING THE GAME AND TURNING VSYNC ON AND OFF USING A METHOD FROM THE INPUT HANDLER CLASS--

                world.correctCamera(camera, window);

                window.update();

                updates++;
                deltaU--;
            }

            if (deltaF >= 1) {
                // --- [ render ] ---
                glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
                world.render(tileRenderer, shader, camera, window);
                window.swapBuffers();

                frames++;
                deltaF--;
            }
            --PRINTING THE FPS AND UPS EVERY SECOND--
        }
```

The input handler methods used:

```
I have this in my constructor:
this.keys = new boolean[GLFW_KEY_LAST];
for(int i = 0; i < GLFW_KEY_LAST; i++)
    keys[i] = false;

And here are the methods: 
public boolean isKeyDown(int key) {
    return glfwGetKey(window, key) == 1;
}
public boolean isKeyPressed(int key) {
    return (isKeyDown(key) && !keys[key]);
}
public void update() {
    for(int i = 32; i < GLFW_KEY_LAST; i++)
        keys[i] = isKeyDown(i);
}
```

This is the render method from the World class:

```
public void render(TileRenderer renderer, Shader shader, Camera camera, Window window) {
    int posX = ((int) camera.getPosition().x + (window.getWidth() / 2)) / (scale * 2);
    int posY = ((int) camera.getPosition().y - (window.getHeight() / 2)) / (scale * 2);
    for (int i = 0; i < view; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < view; j++) {
            Tile t = getTile(i - posX, j + posY);
            if (t != null)
                renderer.renderTile(t, i - posX, -j - posY, shader, world, camera);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the renderTile() method from TileRenderer:

```
public void renderTile(Tile tile, int x, int y, Shader shader, Matrix4f world, Camera camera) {
    shader.bind();
    if (tileTextures.containsKey(tile.getTexture()))
        tileTextures.get(tile.getTexture()).bind(0);

    Matrix4f tilePosition = new Matrix4f().translate(new Vector3f(x * 2, y * 2, 0));
    Matrix4f target = new Matrix4f();

    camera.getProjection().mul(world, target);
    target.mul(tilePosition);

    shader.setUniform("sampler", 0);
    shader.setUniform("projection", target);

    model.render();
}
```

This is the constructor and render method from Model class:

```
public Model(float[] vertices, float[] texture_coords, int[] indices) {
    draw_count = indices.length;

    v_id = glGenBuffers();
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, v_id);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, createBuffer(vertices), GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    t_id = glGenBuffers();
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, t_id);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, createBuffer(texture_coords), GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    i_id = glGenBuffers();
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, i_id);

    IntBuffer buffer = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(indices.length);
    buffer.put(indices);
    buffer.flip();

    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}

public void render() {
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, v_id);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, t_id);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, i_id);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, draw_count, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
}
```

I store the vertices, texture coords and indices in the tile renderer:

```
float[] vertices = new float[]{
            -1f, 1f, 0, //top left     0
            1f, 1f, 0, //top right     1
            1f, -1f, 0, //bottom right 2
            -1f, -1f, 0, //bottom left 3
    };

    float[] texture = new float[]{
            0, 0,
            1, 0,
            1, 1,
            0, 1,
    };

    int[] indices = new int[]{
            0, 1, 2,
            2, 3, 0
    };
```

I don't know what else to put here but the full source code and resources + shader files are available on github [here](https://github.com/TeodorVecerdi/LWJGLTutorial).

Comment: Bundle all your static tiles into a single Model to cut waaaaay down on draw-calls (`glDrawElements()` & co.) & associated state changes.  Also look into texture atlases and/or array textures.

Comment: How can I do that? (Bundling the tiles)

Comment: Instead of having a single quad's worth of geometry in your `vertices`/`texture`/indices` arrays you have an entire layer's worth.

Comment: [also](https://github.com/mattdesl/lwjgl-basics/wiki/Sprite-Batching)

Comment: but still, how do I do that? Should I search on the googles for an answer/tutorial? Like I said, I'm a complete noob and I don't fully understand everything from the tutorials that I watched

Comment: @TeodorVecerdi try looking up `instancing`, which is the technique of using a single draw call to render a mesh multiple times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your current system, what I would recommend doing is grouping your tiles based on texture.  Create something like this:

`Map<Texture, List<Tile>> tiles = new HashMap<Texture, List<Tile>>()`

Then when you go to render your map of tiles, you will only need to set the texture once per group of tiles, rather than once per tile. This saves PCI-E bandwidth for pushing textures/texture ids to the GPU.  You would achieve that like this (pseudo code):

```
for (Texture tex : tile.keySet())
{
    BIND TEXTURE
    for (Tile tile : tiles.get(tex))
    {
        SET UNIFORMS
        RENDER
    }
}
```

Something else I see along these lines is that you are pushing the projection matrix to each tile individually.  When you are running a shader program, the value of a given uniform stays the same until you change it or until the program ends.  Set the projection matrix uniform once.

It also appears that you are calling this every `renderTile(...)`.  Given the value does not change, calculate it once before the render pass, then pass it in as a variable in the `renderTile(...)` method rather than passing in `camera` and `world`.

Comment: So can I get rid of the shader.setUniform() lines and only call it once when I start the game after I set the projection? If I do this how will opengl know where to put the tile since in the second setUniform I pass the target matrix which contains the positions too? I think I misunderstood you.